# How to disable Dungeon generation in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does anyone know how to disable not only villages, but dungeons too in the vanilla game? I do not want to allow my players access to random loot.

Comment: In 1.9 (still upcoming), you'll be able to easily change the loot that things like dungeons have - you can learn a bit more in this guy's youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcKW-m4UeCQ - the relevant part is about 4 minutes 20 seconds in.  This will give you a way to keep the challenge of dungeons without giving them random loot.

Comment: Just a player's opinion, without structures, caving and mining get very boring.

Comment: There are mods that can customize the loot tables rather than disabling generation altogether

Answer (score 13):

You can change dungeon generation, and multiple other settings, in the 'Customised' world type.

On the 'New World' screen, click <kbd>World Type</kbd> until it says 'Customised'. Click on the <kbd>Customise</kbd> button below it.

[image: New world screen]

On the following screen you can change the spawning of dungeons, strongholds, and heaps of other cool stuff. Just click the buttons to toggle, and slide the sliders to change spawn rates.

[image: Customised world settings]

*Please note the 'Dungeon Count' button doesn't actually increase/decrease the number of dungeons, rather it specifies the number of tries per chunk to spawn a dungeon at world generation. While the **average** number of dungeons per chunk may increase, it is **not guaranteed** that any more dungeons will spawn (due to the chance of invalid spawn locations)*

Comment: Increasing the number of tries per chunk indeed do increase the number of dungeons generated overall. Make one world at the minimum and another at the maximum (same seed) and parse the maps with MCMapper, you will see there is a huge difference in dungeons generated. Please use a source for your last paragraph or change it.

Comment: How can I do this on my server?

Comment: @Mindwin He is technically correct. Increasing `Dungeon Count` doesn't directly generate more dungeons, it means that it will _try_ to generate them more times. However, it may end up generating none, if the chunk is not suitable.

Comment: but overall it dramatically creates more. It is the same as buying more raffle tickets. you won't win more than one prize, but the chances you get a prize increases. So statistically over a significant number of raffles, the amount of prizes increse if you buy 30 raffle tickets over than 1. Do the experiment I suggested in the comment above. @MikeCaron

Comment: dungeon count does not increase dungeons *per chunk* (it is either 0 or 1). but over a big number of chunks, it generates more dungeons in the world at a higher setting. So the affirmation is indeed misleading.

Comment: @bird create the world in single player, then copy the world file to your server.

Comment: @angussidney: Depending on the nature of the server, that might or might not continue to work as new chunks are generated.

Comment: @Mindwin Mike is right - it just increases the *chance* of more dungeons spawning - it does not guarantee there will be more dungeons, because it my not find any valid generation spaces - however in practice there will be more overall. I will clarify this in my answer when I can get back on a computer

Comment: @Kevin very good point. It wouldn't.

Comment: @Mindwin Clarified in answer

Answer (score 13):

1. Goto singleplayer and create new world
   [image]
2. Click on more world options
   [image]
3. Click on world type and look for customized. After that click on customize.
   [image]
4. You'll see the basic settings has an option for Villages, Dungeons, etc to turn them off.
   [image]
5. Turn them off.
   [image]
6. Click done and create the world! Now your world will have no villages or dungeons for players to loot.

Hope this was helpful

Comment: Please don't include things like "Hope this helps" and "Your welcome" in future answers.

Comment: I only just beat you to answering with the same solution :)

Comment: Guess we're like minded lol

Answer (score 5):

When creating a new world, click *More World Options*, then click *Generate Structures: ON*. It should change to *OFF*, disabling the spawning of villages, dungeons and strongholds.

Comment: (ignore my last comment if you read it). Since OP wants to block random loot, disabling generated structures also kills Mineshafts, Nether Fortresses (not sure) and the upcoming 1.9 structures too. This is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with a superflat world you can pick a preset then you can see the preset code at the top. It will look something like this:

dungeon,village

So just remove the dungeon and village tag and you should be good to go!